# Why was Mr. Bones not able to be repaired?

Tags: star-wars

In *Aftermath: Empire's End*, the final volume in the *Star Wars: The Aftermath Trilogy*, Mr. Bones (the reprogrammed B-1 battle droid) is destroyed and for some reason it was impossible for him to be re-built.

I lost the book. What was the exact reason why he was essentially dead?

Comment: https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Mister_Bones

Comment: Where is droid's personality stored? In hardware. Possibly some sort of hard disk. Destroyed that piece of hardware and you can't rebuild that droid.

Answer (score 3):

Temmin [had a copy of Mr. Bones's programming](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Mister_Bones#Legacy):

> Unable to give aerial support to his squad leader, Temmin sent Dameron a droid personality template to fight the Rancs, explaining that he always carried the code with him for good luck. Once uploaded into N1-ZX, the commando droid identified itself as "Mister Bones," and in a style reminiscing the original Mister Bones, slaughtered the gang while singing.

However, [it's arguable that it would not have been the same droid](http://freefall.purrsia.com/ff400/fv00383.htm), given that droids often evolve to be more than just their programming, and Temmin would likely not have wished to bring back a partial clone of a beloved friend from childhood who would just serve as a reminder of his loss.

Slightly countering this argument, of course, is that [Mr. Bones had been rebuilt after disintegration before](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Mister_Bones#Joining_the_New_Republic).

> Following the Battle of Akiva, Temmin and Norra rebuilt Mister Bones from scrap in Esmelle and Shirene's basement as a "family project" to make up for the years of separation.

Possibly, this might be explained by that, by the Battle of Jakku, Mr. Bones was starting to malfunction, and Temmin may have chosen to let him rest.

> By the Battle of Jakku, Bones had begun to malfunction due to the damage he had sustained in frequent skirmishes.